# MVC routing, passing array as parameter (Laravel / CodeIgniter style)

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, laravel-5, php-7

I am going over a PHP / MVC / OOP course by Traversy Media and I am on a chapter that creates a router for a simple social app (initial routing of any request throguh `domain.com/index.php`).

The person talks about passing an array as a parameter and I don't get how this works:

```
class Posts {
   public function edit($id) {
      $post = $this->postModel->fetchPost($id); 
      $this->view('edit', ['post' => $post]);
  }
}
```

There is some more simple things in this class but I am just not sure about the `['post' => $post]` part.

I don't get how this syntax works, like sign after sign. Is this based on something that is already builed in into some kind of framework (he does not have anything like this here, this is his and this is the first chapter when he builds it from scratch). I mean, I would imagine that array would be like an `$array`, in a variable and this is a parameter in square brackets, so what is the name of the array here?

Is this `$post` and is the second actual => `$post` a sub-array. I just dont get that at all.

I started learning Laravel previously (skipping this all together for now) and I've been getting stuck on such things too.

I mean, is this like framework-related only (not really a regular procedural PHP), like something that is already coded on a deeper level and we relate to that?

Thank you in advance for any info that I could get.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nyq8xn - this is the whole thing. This is literally the first code that he creates for the project. Again, this is routing all requests through domain.com/index.php. No framework used, his own built from scratch.

Comment: app.com/index.php?url=post/edit/1 - this is the url he is working on, this will be routed to that Object. And I basically dont get that ['post' => $post]

Comment: I mean the [] mean that this is an array, lets say. It looks like an associative array 'post' => $post, so what is the name of this array? Again, I just dont get how this works. Associative array means key => value, so is the name of the array $edit (what is in the code prior to this). Again, I am just not getting it at all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part you are confused about is just a function call.

```
$this-view('edit',['post' => $post]);
```

This could have been written like this

```
$dataYouWantToPassToTheView = ['post' => $post];

$this->view('edit', $dataYouWantToPassToTheView);
```

You are calling the function `view`, and passing it two parameters. An `Edit` String and an Array containing a key `post` with a value of a variable called `post`. The view function simply takes all the values in the array and makes them available by their keys in the view.

This means you can in the view do the following

```
<span>This is post id: {{ $post->id }}</span>
```

Passing an Array as a parameter is regular PHP and has nothing to do with the specific framework. The `Array` doesn't need a "name", just like the `'edit'` `String` doesn't need a name.